# RHEL - Login screen not showing

Tags: linux, rhel

I have a **RHEL 5.6** system which shut down unexpectedly due to a power failure. I restarted the machine to figure out if something is wrong. However, the machine is not showing the login screen. It is stuck after the services listing page.(The page where the OS will notify the loading of services is OK or failed).

I am trying to figure out someway to login to the system.

```
ctrl + alt + F7 - This key combination will allow me to login to the graphical interface. 

ctrl + alt + F1 - This key combination will allow me to login to the command line mode of Linux.
```

Is there any other way to login to the system? Because, the system is stuck and am not pretty sure, even if the above mentioned methods might work.

Answer (score 2):

This is most certainly related to a HDD issue, given the system did not shutdown cleanly. It's either an issue with the physical HDD itself or the journal file that's used by filesystems such as EXT4. I would attempt to boot the system using the installation disk in it's rescue mode, and attempt to repair this.

See the official Redhat documents for more on this.

- http://www.redhat.com/advice/tips/rescue_mode.html

Comment: Or you could boot in runlevel 1 appending "1" to the end of the vmzlinuz row, remount the / in rw with "mount -o remount,rw /" and fsck the fs.